# What is the benefit to using SqLite vs java.SQL on android

Tags: sql

I've been looking through the tutorial : http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

and SQLite seems to have all the basic functionality of Java.SQL

Is there a benefit to using SQLite rather than Java SQL for android development?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this page: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/package-summary.html

Second sentence:

The android.database and android.database.sqlite packages offer a higher-performance alternative where source compatibility is not an issue.

SQLite has higher performance.

java.sql has better source compatibility.

I would assume always use sqlite because source compatibility is not a big issue for android

Answer (score 0):

java.sql is not a database provider as such. It is just a wrapper on top of JDBC. You would need to find a provider with a JDBC driver before you could use it.